# Port forwarding - ASUS RT-N12+ can't open port 25565

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I want to make Minecraft server, so I need to open port 25565. My router is Asus RT-N12+.

Here is what I set up:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEgh0.png)

I check that I opened ports on [canyouseeme.org](http://canyouseeme.org/).
Also, I tried to add the local port as 25565, but I wasn't working.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Have you had anything listen on port 25565 when you tested wit can you see me? If `netstat -an | findstr 25565` comes back empty on your Minecraft server then the test will fail even if you have set up the port forward correctly. First make sure that on the forwarded IP you have anything listening on the port and then test with can you see me.

Comment: It helps to know what tests you've run and what the outcome of each test was. Can you telnet or netcat to the port on the local network?: telnet 192.168.1.148 25565? If that fails, you need to ensure your listening server is up and no firewall on the server is blocking the port. If that works, then try the same test from inside the network using the public IP. If that still works, then the problem is almost certainly with the ISP. Many ISPs block common server ports for popular applications and games on residential circuits.